# ActionMailer values are not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to send email with following configuration

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'lototribe.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp  
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {            
:address              => "smtp.zoho.com", 
:port                 => '465',
:domain               => 'lototribe.com',               
:user_name            => 'no-reply@lototribe.com',
:password             => 'password',         
:authentication       => :plain,
:ssl                  => true,
:tls                  => true,
:enable_starttls_auto => true    
}
```

throwing a Net::ReadTimeout. Om checking the stack trace I found

```
  smtp.start(settings[:domain], settings[:user_name], settings[:password], settings[:authentication]) do |smtp_obj|
    response = smtp_obj.sendmail(message, smtp_from, smtp_to)
  end
```

where

```
  >> settings[:domain]
  => "localhost.localdomain"
  >> settings[:user_name]
  => nil
  >> settings[:password]
  => nil
  >> settings[:authentication]
  => nil
```

which are values never expected.
can anyone tell why these values wrongly set?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting .perform_deliveries to true and change your ActionMailer::Base declaration to config.actionmailer like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  host = ENV['EMAIL_DOMAIN']
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host}
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.zoho.com",
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => ENV["USERNAME"],
    :password => ENV["PASSWORD"],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Another think I like to do is to catch any errors when sending emails because sending emails results almost always in some time type of error. I rescue it so that emails get send out even if some fail:

```
MyMailer.send_email(subject: subject, user: user, message: message).deliver
      rescue Net::OpenTimeout, Net::ReadTimeout, Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError => e
        Rails.logger.error e.message
      end
```